# Accessing Lambda context object in other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I have a NodeJS AWS Lambda function which contains of multiple files. In the index.js I do the regular `exports.handler = function (event,context) {…}`.

I also have a config.js file which handles various settings and module.exports a config object. This config file is required in several other files that all need access to these settings (default values, db settings, etc.). I don't necessarily need to use it in index.js itself.

However, I need to set some settings inside the config module according to the alias of the Lambda function (for example which DynamoDB table suffix to use). While it's no problem to get the alias name via `context.invokedFunctionArn` (in my case PROD or STAGE) inside exports.handler, I don't have access to it in my config file (which is required all over the place).

What would be the best way to make the context object available in my config module and how would I do it without running into circular dependencies (because it is needed before exports.handler is finished)?

Inside exports.handler a lot of async code from multiple files which all require the config is executed. They all need to know which alias is running.

The question is less about how to use aliases but more how to make the context object available in other files.

Thanks!

Comment: The context object will never be available before the handler function is called. You'll need to wait until the handler function is called before you can do anything that requires data from the context object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the variables at the top of your handler before you invoke the async functions:

```
const config = require('./config')
const someAsyncFunction = require('./someAsyncFunction')
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  config.invokedFunctionArn = context.invokedFunctionArn
  someAsyncFunction().then(context.succeed, context.fail)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, these few lines were very helpful. I did it similar before but the config was required by another file that was required by another file (2 levels deep) before, therefore cached and couldn't be (easily) changed anymore. Reading a simplified example helped to clear the mind :-). My config module now contains for a specific setting a function that takes env as param and then returns a prepared instance I need for the environment, and is called by the code that gets executed inside handler. Thanks again for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would alter your async function to take in an "environment" parameter.  Then in your handler, inspect the invoked ARN and extract the alias, then map that to the supported environment type.  Pass that environment as a parameter into your function.

This decouples your other library from any knowledge of the lambda invocation and it makes things easier to test in insolation.  The Lambda handler can be aware of it's alias types, and what they mean.  The code that's actually performing your DynamoDB logic doesn't need to care about that - it just wants to know where it should connect to.